# Moving FB comments at the end of page

Tags: plugins, posts, customization, themes, comments

I am using plugin "wpdevart facebook comment" for posting comments at the end of every post. They are displaying good But now I want to shift those comments little below of pagination and ads Or at the end of the page but comments should be of the relevant post.
attached is the screenshot:
[image]

And for this I have added the plugin shortcode in the Single.php

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    $bimber_post_settings = bimber_get_post_settings();
                    bimber_set_template_part_data( $bimber_post_settings );

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-single-classic-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-single-classic', get_post_format() );
                    comments_template();
                    //facebook comments
                    echo do_shortcode('[wpdevart_facebook_comment facebook_app_id="12345678910111213" curent_url="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" order_type="social" title_text="Facebook Comment" title_text_color="#000000" title_text_font_size="16" title_text_font_famely="Arial" title_text_position="left" width="100%" bg_color="#000000" animation_effect="none" count_of_comments="10" ]');

                    bimber_reset_template_part_data();

                endwhile;
                ?>
```

But It displays all comments of all posts and pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the plugin's user manual.

> **Curent_url** - Type the page URL from where you need to show Facebook
>   comments

So you will have to change the current URL which is (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) to your real current URL.

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
echo do_shortcode('[wpdevart_facebook_comment facebook_app_id="12345678910111213" curent_url="'.$current_url.'
    " order_type="social" title_text="Facebook Comment" title_text_color="#000000" title_text_font_size="16" title_text_font_famely="Arial" title_text_position="left" width="100%" bg_color="#000000" animation_effect="none" count_of_comments="10" ]');
```

Comment: Its not getting the already posted comments which means its only getting the comments that are submitting now.

Comment: try to echo $current_url and be sure it's the right URL, also keep in mind I am using my app_id.

Comment: I just checked your site, and the URL has a lot of blank spaces at the end, that may be a problem. https://i.imgur.com/YTDBjmN.png

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can move comments div out of the "single.php" wrapper.

Changle location of this shortcode `echo do_shortcode('[wpdevart_facebook_comment facebook_app_id="12345678910111213" curent_url="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" order_type="social" title_text="Facebook Comment" title_text_color="#000000" title_text_font_size="16" title_text_font_famely="Arial" title_text_position="left" width="100%" bg_color="#000000" animation_effect="none" count_of_comments="10" ]');`